# Can rip be used with another register with RIP-relative addressing?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, addressing-mode

I'm familiar with memory references of this form:

```
XXX ptr [base + index * size + displacement]
```

where XXX is some size (byte/word/dword/etc), both `base` and `index` are registers, `size` is a small power of two, and `displacement` is a signed value.

amd64 introduced rip-relative addressing. As I understand it, I should be able to use `rip` as a base register. However, when I try this with clang-900.0.39.2:

```
mov r8b, byte ptr [rip + rdi * 1 + Lsomething]
```

I get:

> error: invalid base+index expression
>
> ```
> mov r8b, byte ptr [rip + rdi * 1 + Lsomething]
> ```

Is it impossible to use an index register when using `rip` as the base register? Do I have to use `lea` to compute `rip + Lsomething` and then offset into that?

Comment: RIP + Displacement is the only addressing allowed with RIP relative addressing. So you could use lea to get [rip + Lsomething] and place it in a general purpose register. That register can be used to complete the rest of the address calculation. No real way around the limitation.

Comment: You can find it documented in the  [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) section _2.2.1.6 RIP-Relative Addressing_

Comment: FYI, you *probably* want `movzx r8d, byte ptr [ ...]`, unless you specifically *want* to merge into the existing contents of R8 instead of starting a new dependency chain for that register.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks for the advice. I was writing a toy Meltdown PoC and this is the probe load, so the size or destination doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, `[RIP + rel32]` is the only addressing mode involving RIP.**  See also [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes).

If you want maximum efficiency for indexing a static array, you need to make position-dependent code so you can use the table address as a 32-bit absolute `disp32` in a normal addressing mode.  This is allowed in Linux in position-depended executables, but not shared libraries (which have to be PIC).  See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) for how to use `-fno-pie -no-pie` when gcc is configured by default to make PIEs.

Otherwise for position-independent array indexing, **`lea rsi, [rip + Lsomething]`** and use pointer-increments or `[rsi + rdi*1 + constant]` addressing modes, or whatever other alternative works.  ([Non-indexed addressing modes sometimes save a uop on Intel CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes/31027695#31027695) so pointer-increments can be good, especially if you're unrolling so an `add` for each pointer can more than pay for itself, vs. using the same index for multiple arrays.)

---

It's not "RIP as a base register" in arbitrary addressing modes; **there isn't room in the machine-code encoding for that**.  x86-64 has 16 possible base registers, encoded with 3 bits in the ModR/M or SIB byte + 1 bit in the optional REX prefix.  Making RIP usable as a base with arbitrary addressing modes would have required bumping out some other register, and creating a lot of differences in effective-address decoding between 32 and 64-bit mode.

x86-32 has 2 redundant ways to encode `[0x123456]`, i.e. no-base + disp32: with or without a SIB byte, because SIB has an encoding for no-base and no-index.  See http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#32.2F64-bit_addressing for a nice table, or see Intel's manuals.

The no-index SIB encoding makes it possible to encode `[esp]` instead of `[esp+esp]`, because the ModR/M encoding that would mean base=RSP is the escape code that means "there's a SIB".  They could have designed it so you could use `esp` as an index for bases other than `esp`, but nobody wants to use `esp` as an index in the first place.  Fun fact: the no-base (with `disp32`) encoding uses what would have been the `[ebp]` with no displacement, which is why `[ebp]` is actually encoded as `[ebp + disp8=0]`.  In x86-64 mode, this applies to R13 as well.

**x86-64 re-purposes the shorter (no SIB) encoding for `[disp32]` into `[RIP + disp32]`**, aka `[RIP + rel32]`.

**32-bit absolute addresses (`[disp32]`) are still encodeable with the longer SIB encoding**.  (This is what NASM does by default, if you don't use `default rel`.)  There's not even a `[RIP + disp8]` (e.g. for loading nearby code addresses).  There is exactly one bit-pattern in the Mod and M fields of the ModR/M byte that encodes a RIP-relative address.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Made me figure out [I had to fix the SIB disp32-only encoding](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/306b39bef3da). To be fair, I introduced that error when I [generalised the index=4 special case](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/a2b439f28bce) beyond supporting only SIB=24h (S=0 I=4 B=4), but failed to realise that mod=0 index=4 base=5 is both special cases together. Which reminds me, your text is not entirely accurate: As the S (scale) field is ignored, the SIB disp32-only encoding can actually be encoded in 4 different ways, with S equal to 0, 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: @ecm: Interesting point! There would have been room for a few new addressing modes, if any could be useful.  But no clean way to involve a register number, so as far as being a good compiler target I can see why they wouldn't bother.  Cramming in a limited choice of a few registers would just be a pain to decode, and there's no much I can see worth doing with just a 32-bit constant and RIP or not.  More range by adding or subtracting (or scaling) the 32-bit number isn't needed enough to be worth it.