# Why is a RIP-relative LEA instruction producing a PIC-incompatible R_X86_64_32S relocation?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, addressing-mode, relocation

I'm going through the [x86-64 tutorial on exercism.org](https://exercism.org/tracks/x86-64-assembly/exercises/). I'm using NASM on Linux, producing an ELF binary. There is just a bit of C code that invokes my assembly code in a test harness. Their build system specifies `-pie` in the LDFLAGS and `-fPIE` in the CFLAGS (among others, but those are the most relevant here I think). Therefore, I need (and would like to understand) a solution that uses PIC, which requires RIP-relative addressing.

I have an index (in `rdi`) into an array of 8-byte (qword) values called `values`. I just want to get the address at the offset in order to `mov` the value it points to into a register. Or I would accept `mov`ing the value directly.

I tried this:

```
lea rbx, [rel values + rdi * 8]
```

My understanding is that this will look at the address (relative to `rip`) of `values`, which is in the `data` section, then it will add to that the correct offset (`rdi * 8`) and put that in `rbx`.

But this produces next error:

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: space_age.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
> ```

I understand that `recompile with -fPIE` is the result of the linker thinking that the code was compiled rather than assembled from handwritten assembly. So it seems like NASM is producing a relocation type that is not okay with what it's being linked against, and the linker sees it as not PIE, right?

So I then tried this:

```
lea rbx, [rdi * 8]    ; first compute the offset: index * sizeof(qword value)
lea r8, [rel values]  ; then find the address of the values
add rbx, r8           ; rbx = offset of the array + address of base of the array
```

To me, this is the exact same thing as the first instruction. I don't understand how these differ, but something about the fact that the relocation in the first is `R_X86_64_32S` seems to suggest that the first instruction only has a signed 32 bit offset, and maybe `lea r8, [rel values]` creates a different relocation type that's 64 bits, but I'm just guessing there.

Is this possible to do in one instruction?

---

**Edit**: this is not a duplicate of [this question about addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101) because it did not explain why NASM is accepting my code but then it fails to link. I now understand thanks to the accepted answer that this addressing mode does not exist, but NASM silently ignores the `rel` part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)

Comment: You can't use `[rel values]`, which is to say `[rip + values]`, together with an index register.  No such addressing mode is supported by the CPU.   This is not about relocations; `lea rbx, [rel values + rdi * 8]` is simply not an encodable instruction.  You can have `[disp + base + index * scale]`, or `[rip + disp]`, but not both together.

Comment: @NateEldredge if that's not encodable instruction, then how does nasm assemble it? nasm runs fine on that code, it just fails during linking.

Comment: Yeah, good question.  It looks like nasm just ignores the `rel` and treats it as `lea rbx, [values + rdi * 8]`, which is encodable but is not what you want, and in particular would require the problematic relocation.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The best duplicate about how addressing modes work is [Can rip be used with another register with RIP-relative addressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48124293) but that's using GAS `.intel_syntax`, so it doesn't mention NASM.  I agree with Hut8 that it would be better if NASM at least warned when `rel` is used explicitly in an addressing mode it can't support, rather than just `default rel` globally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such instruction as `lea rbx, [rel values + rdi * 8]`, or in other words `lea rbx, [values + rip + rdi * 8]`.  The `rip`-relative addressing mode cannot be combined with an index register (with or without scaling).  See [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)

Unfortunately, it looks like nasm handles this by just ignoring the `rel` and assembling `lea rbx, [values + rdi * 8]`, which would require the problematic relocation.  The address of `values` would have to go in the 32-bit displacement field of the instruction's memory operand, but that is impossible since `values` need not be located in the lowest or highest 2 GB of memory; hence the confusing error message.

But the correct solution is that you just have to write more instructions.  You can get the desired effect in two instructions with

```
lea rbx, [rel values]
lea rbx, [rbx + rdi * 8]
```

Or if you want to actually do the load:

```
lea rbx, [rel values]
mov rcx, [rbx + rdi * 8]
```

(The choices of registers are arbitrary.)

Comment: Wow, silently ignoring the `rel` seems like a bug. Answer accepted!

Comment: @Hut8: I think so too.  I'll try to file a bug report and link it here.

Comment: I already filed one: https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392797

Comment: @Hut8: Oh, great.  I was still waiting for my Bugzilla account to be approved.

Comment: https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/pull/29 - now nobody will have to wonder any more; I added a warning to NASM and my merge request was merged by H. Peter Anvin!